# работа с enum class

Tags: c++

у меня есть два enum class

```
enum class enum_1{ A,B,C };
enum class enum_2{ A,B,C };
```

есть два вектора

```
vector<enum_1> vec_1;
vector<enum_2> vec_2;
```

как мне переложить в vec_2, в котором лежат элементы enum_2, элементы enum_1, которые лежат в vec_1?
я пробовал как-то так:

```
vector<enum_2> Function() const {

    std::vector<enum_1> vec_1{ 
             enum_1::A,
             enum_1::B,
             enum_1::C
    };

    vector<enum_2> vec_2;
    for (auto i = 0; i < vec_1.size(); i++)
    {
            enum_2 tmp= static_cast<enum_2>(vec_1[i]);
            vec_2.push_back(tmp);
    }
    return result;
}
```

я не уверен, что так вообще можно делать

Comment: Какой смысл иметь разные `enum class` в данном случае?

Comment: @älёxölüt
ну они могут быть в разных классах, и мне надо в классе в котором enum_2 в вектор положить элементы из класса в котором enum_1

Comment: Можно использовать приведение типа к int и таким образом пушить данные в vec_2. Так как у тебя индексы элементов и значения enum одинаковые (да и вообще, enum class'ы идентичные), то при пуше интов будут те же самые элементы. Не понятно на самом деле зачем нужна такая задача, но если интересует, могу предоставить код

Comment: @user9431986 так объяви enum вне всяких классов и будет тебе счастье

Comment: @Ladence если не сложно, покажите пожалуйста

Comment: нельзя вне классов объявить

Comment: Почему нельзя? Кто запретил?

Comment: ну я не так выразился, наверное

Comment: у меня два класса, в каждом есть один и тот же enum class, и мне не то что с кастить надо значения, мне надо переложить значения из одного вектора с enum_1 в другой вектор c enum_2

Comment: Что значит "один и  от же", если у вас в примере явно показаны два разных независимых enum?

Answer (score 1):

> я не уверен, что так вообще можно делать

Можно. С вашим кодом все нормально.

При преобразовании в `enum` неопределенное поведение возникает, если преобразовываемое число не влезает в допустимый диапазон этого `enum`a.

У `enum class`ов underlying type - всегда `int`, если не указан явно ([пруф](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)). Поэтому диапазон у двух `enum`ов в вопросе одинаковый, и проблем быть не может.

Даже будь это простые `enum` (не `class`), допустимый диапазон все равно совпадал бы из-за того, что константы в них лежат одинаковые.

---

Кстати, `auto` вот тут:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < vec_1.size(); i++)
```

выглядит подозрительно. Он всегда определяется как `int`, а более правильно было бы иметь здесь тип `std::size_t`.

Comment: то есть формально, код, который я привел делает то, что мне нужно?

Comment: @user9431986 Угу.

Comment: а если мне не скастить надо, а прям взять и руками переложить значения из одного в другое, как такое сделать?

Comment: @user9431986 Не понял. А с кастом это что, не перекладывание руками?

Answer (score 0):

Как и обещал, код. Но только опять же не понимаю смысл этой задачи

```
#include <vector>

enum class FirstEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

enum class SecondEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

std::vector<SecondEnum> func()
{
    std::vector<FirstEnum> vec_1{FirstEnum::A, FirstEnum::B, FirstEnum::C};

    std::vector<SecondEnum> result;

    for (auto i{ 0 }; i < vec_1.size(); i++)
    {
        result.push_back(static_cast<SecondEnum>(vec_1[i]));
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto result = func();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если перечисления реально одинакового набора, то я бы вовсе не стал заводить разные `enum` (тем более делать их `enum class`) для этих целей. Но коли уж типы различны, то задача преобразования вектора объектов одного типа в другой - это вполне себе отдельная задача и для её решения есть стандартная функция [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). Применительно к типам перечислений это могло бы выглядеть примерно так:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

enum class E1 { A, B, C };
enum class E2 { A, B, C };

int main() {

    std::vector<E1> v1 { E1::A, E1::B, E1::C };

    std::vector<E2> v2;

    std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), 
                   [](auto e1) { return static_cast<E2>(static_cast<int>(e1)); });

}
```